# Tile an image with SFML

Tags: c++, textures, sprite, sfml, repeat

I have a background image and it's only 256 x 256 when my window is 800 x 600.  I'm not sure how to get the image to repeat itself across the whole window.  I currently load the image in  with:

```
sf::Texture Bkg;
if(!Bkg.loadFromFile("darkPurple.png"))
{
    return -1;
}

sf::Sprite Sprite;
Sprite.setTexture(Bkg);
```

and the draw it later with:

```
window.draw(Bkg);
```

I tried to use:

```
texture.setRepeated(true);
```

but that didn't seem to help.

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, if you're trying to color your background, you don't need a jpg, you can just use this: `window.clear(sf::Color(128,0,128));` provided that "window" is a RenderWindow object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you load the image you need to call setReapeted:

```
    texture.setRepeated(true);
```

And after that, when load texture in your sprite, set the texture rect to be to your size of screen:

```
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,800,600);
```